# random bursts of CPU activity

Tags: 11.10, wubi, cpu, cpu-load

I am running a wubi installation of ubuntu 11.10 64 bit and every hour or so there is a random burst of activity where the CPU is at 100% and I have trouble just browsing on firefox. This can last from a minute to five minutes and makes my CPU really hot. I took a `htop` screenshot when one of these bursts happened and it looks like the culprit is `mount`.

So, what the hell is `mount` doing that needs so much CPU attention and how do I stop it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if it runs every hour, then it is probably a cron job, try taking a look at the jobs in

```
/etc/cron.hourly
```

The cause may well be indirect, `mount` could be triggered by all sorts of things, like udev rules firing for whatever reason. If it is trying to mount an unclean filesystem it will have to do quite a bit of work to check it first.
If you never want to mount this partition from linux, you should probably ignore it in your `/etc/fstab`